# Warning: Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

I have got following message:

> Warning: Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null.

My code looks like (it is simplified, so useless):

```
public class MyEntity
{
    // ...
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    string dbMyProp;

    public string MyProp { get { return dbMyProp.Replace("a", "b"); } }

    public static readonly Expression<Func<MyEntity, MyClass>> FromMyEntity = e => new MyClass
    {
        dbMyProp = e.MyProp // ...
    };
}
```

I think that the message is not true.

Is it a bug in C# compiler or I have missed something?

*UPDATE* The field is `dbMyProp`. It is simplified but it still produces this warning.

*UPDATE2* The following code does not produce such warning:

```
public class MyClass2
{
    string dbMyProp;

    public string MyProp { get { return dbMyProp.Replace("a", "b"); } }

    public static MyClass2 FromMyEntity(MyEntity e)
    {
        return new MyClass2 
        {
            dbMyProp = e.MyProp // ...
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: As you said, your code is simplified and therefore we can't necessarily tell what's the cause of the problem.  You also don't include which variable the warning is raised for.

Comment: Re your edit, again - this all comes down to the fact that your original code is an `Expression`. An `Expression` *is not the same* as usual code.

Comment: I see that difference. It was a response to other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems a shortcoming of the compiler. It apparently cannot see through (does not include) the Expression.
The following prints "bbc" as expected:

```
var exp = MyClass.FromMyEntity.Compile();
var mc = exp(new MyEntity { MyProp = "abc"});
Console.WriteLine(mc.MyProp);
```

I tried a few tricks like a private constructor on MyClass but the warning remains.

It seems the compiler applies a more conservative algorithm, only checking if any (normal) member assigns to `dbMyProp` .

---

<strike>You are confusing things by having 2 different elements with the name `dbMyProp` but `MyEntity.MyProp` is never written to here.</strike>

Comment: that is unrelated; if you take all the `MyProp` stuff away, but leave the `dbMyProp` assignment - it *still* thinks that `dbMyProp` is unused.

Answer (score 6):

An `Expression` **is not code**. It is *intent*; so at the *compiler* level, it could indeed be argued that no code actually ever assigns that field. There is a `MemberAssignment` (from `Expression.Bind`), but that is unrelated.

That would only by an actual field assignment if the expression were compiled. And that would be reflection at runtime, which the compiler does not attempt to detect.

Here is what that *actually* is at compile-time:

```
static MyClass()
{
    ParameterExpression CS$0$0000;
    FromMyEntity = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, MyClass>>(
      Expression.MemberInit(
        Expression.New(
          (ConstructorInfo)methodof(MyClass..ctor),
          new Expression[0]
        ),
        new MemberBinding[] {
          Expression.Bind(
            fieldof(MyClass.dbMyProp),
            Expression.Property(
              CS$0$0000 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyEntity), "e"),
              (MethodInfo)methodof(MyEntity.get_MyProp)
            )
          )
        }
      ),
      new ParameterExpression[] {
        CS$0$0000
      }
    );
}
```

Note what **isn't** there is any assignment to a field; just use of the imaginary `fieldof` operator (meaning: it embeds the field handle directly - it doesn't use a `string` of the name).

And by the same logic, the warning *goes away* if we make it a delegate:

```
public static readonly Func<MyEntity, MyClass> FromMyEntity = e => new MyClass
{
    dbMyProp = e.MyProp // ...
};
```

Now this *is* code; it is not just an object-model showing "here's what I *would* do, ***if*** I were compiled".

Comment: I understand that the compiler cannot resolve setting by reflection. But it can process that during generation of the expression tree. What is different for the user here between static function which may or may not be called.

Comment: @TN an `Expression` *is not a function*; it is *never* called (it ***cannot*** be called/invoked) - it is just an object model that *describes* some code you typed. That is the key difference. Typically, you inspect an `Expression` at runtime, but that has nothing to do with actually executing it. The only way to execute it is to compile the `Expression` at runtime.

Comment: Functions can be called and expressions can be compiled (e.g. to IL, to SQL, ...) and then may be called too. (Just do not think that the probability is lower.)

Comment: @TN an expression can be compiled *at runtime*. The build-time compiler does not attempt to know what you are doing at runtime. At build-time, it is entirely correct to say: that field is never assigned. Specifically, there is no `stfld` that operates against it. Your "can be compiled" is no different to saying a *string* "can be compiled" (via `CSharpCodeProvider`). Entirely accurate, yet entirely irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Yes, but is this correct from user perspective? Compiler can see that (unlike reflection, since it is generating that expression) but does not expect that this will be compiled/called?

Comment: @TN actually, no: the fast majority of expressions are **not** compiled; they are processed by tools like ORMs or RPC stacks, which read the tree and make their *own* IL to achieve a similar result, but via their own internal goo. If the user was just going to compile it, then frankly they shouldn't be using an `Expression` in the first place.

Comment: What about LINQ-to-SQL or NHibernate compiler to SQL?

Comment: @TN L2S and NH are ORMs; they *do not* call `.Compile()`. They do what I just described - read the tree and do their own thing (for example, substituting big chunks with `IDataReader` access).

Comment: I was not saying that they are calling `.Compile()` (to compile it into IL). But they are compiling it into SQL.

Comment: @TN SQL does not assign fields to objects instances, but again: what happens at runtime is *not the concern* of the compiler. The compiler is speaking the truth when it says: that field is never assigned, based on what is known at compile-time.

Comment: Not sure. Is it known that the static function in update2 will be called, no. But in compile-time is known that user is generating the expression to assign that variable. What is the difference for the user? (The message does not says that compiler that the message is only for IL.)

Comment: @TN it is known that the static function in update2 *exists*. Thus: there is code that could lead to that field becoming assigned. The compiler does not attempt to understand all possible code-paths to figure out every method that can be reached - that is simply a re-statement of the well-known "halting problem". So it does what it can, which is: *can I see any code that actually assigns this field*. `Expression` is not included in that, for all the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: Still, I do not understand the decision why are the compiler-generated expressions not included - I do not see the "halting problem" there.

Answer (score 0):

It's NOT a bug in the compiler.

Pls. see the answer by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)

The following explanation is not correct.

---

The warning is displayed becaues in following scenerio the unassigned value of `dbMyProp` will be used. 1. MyClass is instantiated. 2. Using the instance `MyProp` property is called. (Which will lead to `NullReferenceException`)

Comment: "... never assigned to, and will ALWAYS have its default value null" - that is not true?

Comment: The statement is true during compile time state of program. You can manually assign to `null` and see the warning is gone.

Comment: It's true for the current instance. Just write the following code and you will see how true it is: `var myprop = new MyClass().MyProp;`.

Comment: I agree with your first line, but I strongly disagree with the rest; that is unrelated. The C# shown **does not** contain any C# code that assigns the field. It looks like it does, but it does not.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes, after reading Update2 by OP, I agree with you. Now trying to understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> or I have missed something?

You have missed something. Inside the lambda expression you created a **new** instance of the `MyClass` and assigned its `dbMyProp` field. But you never assigned the `dbMyProp` field of the **current** instance inside an instance method.

Check this example out:

```
var instance = new MyClass();
var myProp = instance.MyProp; // BOOM - you never assigned a value to the dbMyProp field
```

Comment: Well, you know instance field means that in order to access it you need to have a current instance of the object. So imagine someone creating a new instance of MyClass from the outside like: `var instance = new MyClass();`. The `dbMyProp` field of this instance is never assigned value. And since it is a private field the only place you could assign it a value is an instance method of the class or the constructor of course. See my updated example.

Comment: The compiler should have produced a warning in this case as well because you never assign a value to the private field. I guess the compiler is not perfect after all :-)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I disagree; in the edit, there is a clear assignment (a `stfld`) to `dbMyProp`. In the original code, there is not: there is just an `Expression`. Expressions are not regular code.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I perfectly agree with your in-depth technical explanation of what's going on under the covers. Thank you for that. But I am looking it from a developer/user perspective: In both cases as a consumer of the class I get a NRE if I try to use `MyProp` of a newly created instance of the class. In the first case the compiler warns me, in the second it doesn't. Of course as a developer of this class I would probably have marked the constructor as private so that all instance of this class are created through the specific static method which is effectively setting the private field.